# Compiler error when throwing exception

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am currently learning about exceptions handling, and here is part of my code:

```
//vector.cpp

#include "vector.h"

Vector::Vector(int s)
{
    if (s < 0) throw length_error{};
    elem = new double[s];
    sz = s;
}
```

here is the code I am trying to test the exception by:

```
try{
    Vector v(-27);
}
catch (length_error)
{
    cout << "There was a negative size for your vector.\n";
}
catch (bad_alloc)
{
    cout << "The memory was not allocated properly.\n";
}
```

When I try to run my application, I get the following error:

```
error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'initializer-list' to 'std::length_error'
```

Where is the error?

EDIT: The code was copied from [C++ Programming Language Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321563840).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to cppreference.com [`std::length_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/length_error) has the two constructors:

```
explicit length_error( const std::string& what_arg );
explicit length_error( const char* what_arg );
```

And you are trying to construct with an empty parameters list. You need to pass in a string to the constructor.

Comment: see my edit! why can the author write it like that, and I can't? :))

Comment: I'd say your compiler proves the author wrong, if indeed your code is an *exact* copy out of that book. Or, the author knows C++ better than your compiler.

Comment: have you taken a look at who is the author of my book?

Comment: Section 19.2.4 of the standard [length.error] confirms that those are the only valid constructors. If there is an example that shows this being constructed with no parameters then either the example is wrong or they are using a compiler specific extension.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can search inside the book on [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/gp/reader/0321563840/ref=sib_dp_ptu#reader-link) (find "`length_error`", page 56). He does indeed write `throw length_error{};`

Comment: Bjarne does have an [errata page](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th_printing3.html), nothing for 4th Ed. yet as far as I can see. Consider sending him a "bug report", although I would suspect he's already aware of it. His email address is written in semi-obfuscated format at the bottom of [the front page](http://www.stroustrup.com/index.html).

Comment: Well it does appear that there is indeed a mistake in the book despite the author...